# Installed mui with styled-engine but it's asking for emotion

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I tried installing Material UI (`mui`), and followed the instructions in their guide for if you're using styled components:

```
npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc
```

When I import a component into a file, I get the error

> Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in '(...my path...)/node_modules/@mui/styled-engine'
>
> node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/index.js

Why is it looking for emotion when I followed the directions for using styled-components??

---

The full directions actually say

```
npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components
```

But of course we're already using styled components. I tried this anyway, same problem.

Now the truth is that we're actually using React 16.4, and MUI requires React 17. I installed with `--legacy-peer-deps`. It doesn't seem, though, like the error I'm getting should have to do with the version of React I'm using?

Comment: Did you follow the [package resolution steps](https://mui.com/guides/styled-engine/#yarn) in the documentation?

Comment: @RyanCogswell I did not, that fixed it! Post as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.